# Replace Â£ with £

Tags: php, character-encoding, replace

I am trying to replace `Â£` with `£` and it did not work.

I've tried:

```
echo str_replace("Â£", "£", "Â£3 Discount Discount");
```

I have also tried `html_entity_decode` which also did not work.

Comment: It seems that you rather should convert the string from UTF-8 to ISO 8859-1 or some other single-byte character encoding you are using.

Comment: Is the text coming from a database?

Comment: @SpaceBeers Yes from database.

Comment: Testing the statement in isolation, I get the expected result “£3 Discount Discount”. Are you sure that you tested exactly this construct, with string literals, instead of using a parameter that is *assumed* to contain a certain string? And why did you try `html_entity_decode` on some data that clearly contains nothing resembling an HTML entity reference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an issue with trying to display UTF-8–encoded data as non–UTF-8. You need to make sure that all character encodings are consistent, and if not then you're converting between them appropriately. The easiest way is to ensure that **absolutely everything** is in UTF-8. This includes:

- The data that's saved in the database (MySQL's character set / collation)
- The client connection to the database (Using `SET NAMES UTF-8`)
- The output to the browser (`header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`)
- The PHP script containing the code (yes, this sometimes has an impact)

I would first suggest checking that there isn't any mojibake in your database (e.g. using phpMyAdmin or command-line client), before checking the character sets above. If you find that the database actually contains `Â£`, then I would suggest applying the same logic above to any *input* mechanism to the database (including character encoding of HTML forms).

(Note: I've assumed MySQL throughout this answer.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're able try and use `&pound;` instead of the `£` character and save yourself the trouble.

Comment: It is not that. I already have list of data stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try cleaning it up in the DB instead. Adapt this query to suit your needs.

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE_NAME SET THE_ROW = REPLACE(THE_ROW , 'Â£', '&pound;');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try [`utf8_decode()`](http://php.net/utf8-decode) instead.

Comment: In what way did it "not work"? Did it not do anything at all? What exactly did you try?

Comment: It did not change the string and did not replace anything. `echo utf8_decode("Â£3 Discount Discount");`

Comment: Okay, the point is there are two £ characters in Unicode, for some reason. Maybe there's a tiny difference between them, I don't know. What I'm getting at is, are you using the right one in the right place to fix the problem?

Comment: Unicode has U+00A3 POUND SIGN “£” and U+20A4 LIRA SIGN “₤” which may look rather similar. But the latter is *very* rare, and the code posted contains only occurrences of POUND SIGN.